# IF Else in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use below query but says `Incorrect syntax near if` how to solve this problem?

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCustomerAllReseller
(
    @code BIGINT 
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    WITH Directories AS 
    (
        IF (@code < 0)
            SELECT code FROM CustomerAll WHERE code = @code
        ELSE
            SELECT code FROM Customer WHERE code = @code
    )
    SELECT * FROM Directories
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getCustomerAllReseller
(
    @code BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT code 
    FROM dbo.CustomerAll 
    WHERE code = @code
        AND @code < 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT code 
    FROM dbo.Customer 
    WHERE code = @code
        AND @code >= 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `with` expects a query, not a statement. You can use conditions in a query with a union:

```
WITH Directories AS (
  select code from CustomerAll where @code<0 and code=@code
  union all
  Select code from Customer where @code>=0 and code=@code
)
SELECT * FROM Directories
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `IF`, you must use `SELECT` for `CTE_definition_part`:

> Specifies a SELECT statement whose result set populates the common
>   table expression. The SELECT statement for CTE_query_definition must
>   meet the same requirements as for creating a view, except a CTE cannot
>   define another CTE. For more information, see the Remarks section and
>   CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx